# Would there be a way to find all facebook users who graduated from a high school on a certain year?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Would there be a way to find all Facebook users who graduated from a high school on a certain year?

I mean like using the Graph API, or something? and I mean to search all users, not just friends.

Comment: Gah... trying to implement reunion.com on top of facebook?

Comment: you could try some fql, mainly query the user table, but i don't think it'll get you what you want, you'll have to build the user base, one by one, and then give suggestions to people with same education history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid not. The graph api can be used only in context of a profile ( that is you can only play around with friends data)